# TypeError: Cannot cast DatetimeArray to dtype datetime64[D]

Tags: python, pandas

I recently updated my python install from 3.11.2 to 3.11.3, pandas version is 2.0.2

I am now getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast DatetimeArray to dtype datetime64[D]
```

When I try to perform this:

```
df = df[df['CancelDate'].astype('datetime64[D]') >= (datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=2))]
```

On this dataframe:

```
mydataset = {
    'CancelDate': ["2021-09-07", "2021-07-26", "2021-11-01","2015-06-15"]
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(mydataset)
```

Prior to the update, I was not getting the given error. Could anyone help me realize the error in my ways?

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: Here we mean pandas version.

Comment: yes because in pandas version 1.4, the `astype` method no longer supports casting a `DatetimeArray` object to a `datetime64[D]`.

Comment: You could try to use `to_datetime` if your input data is in string format: `df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['CancelDate']) >= (datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=2))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue, you can use the `pd.pd.to_datetime` function to convert the 'CancelDate' column to a `DatetimeArray` before performing the comparison.

```
df['CancelDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CancelDate'])  # Convert to DatetimeArray
df = df[df['CancelDate'] >= (datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=2))]
```

Answer (score 2):

to fix your issue you can use `dt` accessor to extract the date component of the `CancelDate` column and then cast it to `datetime64[D]`

for example :

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd

mydataset = {
    'CancelDate': ["2021-09-07", "2021-07-26", "2021-11-01","2015-06-15"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydataset)

df['CancelDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CancelDate'])
df = df[df['CancelDate'].dt.date >= (datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=2)).date()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm ignorant, but why are you casting to a specific datetime dtype in the first place?

BTW, no need to use `datetime` either.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df[pd.to_datetime(df['CancelDate']) >= (pd.Timestamp.now() - relativedelta(years=2))]
```