# Exception from .astype() on a large scale dataframe, how to find which line cause the problem

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a large scale dataframe `'df'` with a column called invoice_date. When I try to apply astype on this column:

```
df.astype({'invoice_date': np.dtype('datetime64')})
```

I got this error:

> Cannot cast DatetimeArray to dtype datetime64[D]

I try to sample first several rows of this `df` and they work well. I want to know which line cause this error. How can I tell it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76509006/typeerror-cannot-cast-datetimearray-to-dtype-datetime64d